# How do I show this series diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The series in question is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+5}$$

If $a_n$ is the $n$'th term of this sum, then $a_n \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I believe this implies that the series doesn't converge - since this is effectively the negation of the statement "If a series converges, then $a_n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$". If I prove that the sequence $x_n=\frac{n^2 + 1}{2n^2 +5}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$, have I then proven that the series diverges? Or should I apply a convergence test and show that it doesn't pass one?

Comment: That will be sufficient

Comment: Pertaining to the sequence or to the convergence test?

Comment: "If I prove that the sequence $x_n=\frac{n^2 + 1}{2n^2 +5}$ converges to $\frac{1}{2}$, have I then proven that the series diverges?"  Yes you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The infinite series $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+5}$$ diverges because the term $$\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+5}\to 1/2 \not=0$$

Intuitively you are adding infinitely many  numbers which are very close to $1/2$ and the result does not converge.

The so called divergence test indicates that if the general term of a series does not tend to zero, then the series diverges.

You do not have to prove anything else for the divergence of the above series.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*

As already said, the problem is over as soon as you showed that the term tends to anything which is not zero.

If fact, we can even approximate the partial sums
$$\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+5}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4 \left( n^2+\frac52\right)}$$
Now, use partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{ n^2+\frac52}=\frac 1{(n+i\sqrt{\frac 52})(n-i\sqrt{\frac 52})}=\frac 1 {2a}\left(\frac 1{n-a} -\frac 1{n+a} \right)$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac 1{n+a} = H_{p+a}-H_a\qquad \text{and}\qquad \sum_{n=1}^p\frac 1{n-a} = H_{p-a}-H_{-a}$$ and using the asymptotics
$$H_q=\gamma +\log \left({q}\right)+\frac{1}{2 q}-\frac{1}{12
   q^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^3}\right)$$ After some minor simplifications of the complex numbers, you should end with
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{n^2+1}{2n^2+5}=\frac{p}{2}+\frac{3}{40} \left(2- \sqrt{10}\, \pi  \,\coth \left(\sqrt{\frac{5}{2}} \pi
   \right)\right)+\frac{3}{4 p}-\frac{3}{8 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ Try it for $p=10$; the exact value is 
$$S_{10}=\frac{255436901298463}{57072223853645}\approx 4.47568 $$ while the truncated expansion given above leads to $4.47608$.